# Referencing two foreign keys in one table - SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have 3 tables ("main_service_approval", "main_inventory" and "proc_supplier_list")

In the ("main_service_approval") there are two foreign keys referencing to ("main_inventory") and ("proc_supplier_list")

Please refer the link for the diagram
http://s6.postimg.org/ecygesdch/diagram.jpg

I know how to use the following statements to retrieve ("main_service_approval") and ("proc_supplier_list")

```
SELECT item_id FROM   main_inventory WHERE  main_service_approval.item = main_inventory.name
```

and

```
SELECT sup_id FROM   proc_supplier_list WHERE  main_service_approval.supplier = proc_supplier_list.name
```

But I don't know how to enter this after creating an sql command in C#

please help in the following code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@" THE CODE NEEDED ", cn);
```

Comment: Why do not use `main_service_approval.item_id = main_inventory.item_id` and  `main_service_approval.sup_id = proc_supplier_list.sup_id` ? You can try to use `UNION`

Comment: Are you basically asking how to query multiple tables in a single SQL statement?

Comment: @MegaTron I don't now to use UNION commands, if you could provide me an example for this, it would be good.

Comment: @ Damien I want make a Service approval where I need to link the supplier id and item id into my table

Comment: Ok, it's not porblem but tell us what do you want to get all data from main_service_approval and linked entities from main_inventory and proc_supplier_list ?

Comment: yes, its like this...      I want to enter a record to service approval, and I by the time I enter the details and press submit, I want to auto generate the supplier id and item id in the record

Comment: its like this....       I have two table s filled with data (proc_supplier_list & main_inventory)...       I have a third table linked to a form called (main_service_approval)...  I want to insert data to the service_approval form where supplier_id of (proc_supplier_list) and item_id of (main_inventory) should be auto generated and inserted in (main_service_approval) in the respective column

Answer (score -1):

You can execute SQL queries in C# as below:-

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

However, you can use **CommandType.StoredProcedure** if query using Stored Procedure. Similarly if you want only single column from query, then use like **cmd.ExecuteScalar()**.

Comment: in general you should be instantiating `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` with a `using` statement without calling `SqlConnection.Close()` explicitly.